Yii2 mongodb query way faster in shell then php
mongo shell
db.runCommand({explain:{count:'galleries',query:{ "$and": [{ "status": { "$eq": "published" }, "type": { "$ne": "picture" }, "series": { "$in": [ " there are 96 items here " ] } }, { "publishedAt": { "$lte": " DATE " } }] }}});


execution stats for mongo shell
 executionStats: {
    executionSuccess: true,
    nReturned: 0,
    executionTimeMillis: 49,
    totalKeysExamined: 28682,
    totalDocsExamined: 0,


vs
$filters = ['$and' => [["status" => ['$in' => ["published"]], "type" => ['$nin' => ["video"]], "photos" => ['$exists' => true, '$not' => ['$size' => 0]], "series" => ['$in' => [" 96 items "]]], ["publishedAt" => ['$lte' => " DATE "]]]];
        
        $collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('galleries');

        $count = $collection->count($filters);

execution stats for php
"planningTimeMicros": 3296,
    "keysExamined": 27998,
    "docsExamined": 27946,
    "fromPlanCache": true,
    "durationMillis": 412


the ONLY difference that i've saw is that on php all the docs are examined .... Why? i can't find a reason!
both are using same index!!!
latest php and mongo are used!

"the ONLY difference that i've saw is that on php all the docs are examined" - well this doesn't seem to be the case at all. For example the second query has a predicate on photos that is absent form the first query. Limitations on covering with multikey indexes may apply. Show us the full outputs (maybe link to gists if they are too long to be pasted directly here) or we'll just be guessing and can't help. Probably a better question for dba.stackexchange.com anyway

yes! correct! i've mixed up the queries. here are the complete outputs for same query gist
